# Flask SQLAlchemy MySql Error 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, flask, sqlalchemy

I am hosting my flask website on ubuntu 18.04 server but I am using Flask SQLAlchemy to connect to my database previously (30-45 days ago) I connected it successfully but now I am getting this error -

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I am using the following code to connect to the database from my flask website -

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql://root:helloworld@localhost/vit"
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "localhost"
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = "helloworld"
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "vit"
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = "DictCursor"
```

I tried to create a new user in MySQL by native password, I tried to grant all privileges to root, I tried to also change the password of the root, I also tried to use mysql+pymysql in SQLALchemy URI. But no one method is working.

Kindly suggest to me any solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you log in to MySQL with this password and username on your terminal or any database managing application?

Comment: Yes, I am able to log in.